# Entity Framework get a select command object from a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I got a simple stored procedure which returns a few columns from a much bigger table with a small term.

Something like this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spTemp @Type nvarchar(25)
AS
    SELECT DISTINCT gType, gYear, gModel
    FROM MyTableOnDB
    WHERE gType = @Type
GO
```

I also got an object to fill the data into. Something like :

```
public class info
{
   public string Type {get; set;}
   public string Model {get; set;}
   public int year {get; set;}
}
```

What would be the right / best  way to connect the object to the returned value of the procedure with Entity Framework in mind?

P.S. I am using SQL Server, EF, C#.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using EF, your stored entity will get created in your solution.  you can call your Stored Procedure and convert to Entity Type. Here is sample way

```
 return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<info>("spTemp", Type);
```

Answer (score 0):

as the link [Stored-Procedure](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx) you can import the stored procedures in the VS 
and use them to generate data .

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the stored procedure into the model. It will create a new complex type with the name  {sp name}_Result.

you will not need the complex type for your query so remove this by right clicking on the function import in the project explorer in this dialog change the return type to return the appropriate entities.

when complete You will see the function in the class.

you can then run the procedure by something like this:

```
using (var context = new tempDBEntities())
{
    var type = context.spTemp(1);

    foreach (gType cs in gTypes)
        Console.WriteLine(cs.gType);
}
```

I have adapted this from the tutorial here, please let me know if you get it working. I am trying to upskill in entity framework.

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx